# Apple Push Notification with Sending Custom Data

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am sending push notifications from php job application to iphone. I am sending push notifications regarding new jobs. Is this possible that when user click on the view of push notification pop up , then user redirect to the particular job in the device.

I mean I wanted to know can I send any custom data with push notification like jobId,something else....so that Iphone end Can retrieve and show the particular job ?

Thanks.

Comment: oh..sorry rckones..I didnt know how to accpt as answer..my fault..now sorted it out... :)

Comment: We are all here to learn.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Regardless of the language and library you use, the push notification payload is a JSON payload:

```
{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 10,
         "alert": "Hello world!",
         "sound": "cat.caf"
    }
}
```

The `aps` token is the Apple APN data. You can add custom data to your payload as well:

```
{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 10,
         "alert": "Hello world!",
         "sound": "cat.caf"
    },
    "job_id": 1
}
```

When you receive the notification in the app, check for your param in the notification dictionary:

```
- (void)handleBackgroundNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *aps = (NSDictionary *)[notification objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSMutableString *alert = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    if ([aps objectForKey:@"alert"])
    {
        [alert appendString:(NSString *)[aps objectForKey:@"alert"]];
    }
    if ([notification objectForKey:@"job_id"])
    {
        // do something with job id
        int jobID = [[notification objectForKey:@"job_id"] intValue];
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the total size of the payload is 256 *bytes*, and that includes, of course, your custom parameters. So you may have to (at risk of reducing readability) call your custom param "ji" instead of "job_id" to squeeze bytes.

All of this is documented in the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) in the iOS documentation. Definitely would recommend a read because it's more complex than it initially sounds (at least, that's what I thought).

Comment: How can I add custom data to the payload?

Comment: @JoshHarington  "job_id": 1 is a custom data in the payload

Comment: From iOS 8 the payload size has been increased to 2KB from 256 bytes :)

Comment: Are you getting custom data payload in iOS 10?

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can send custom data, check [apns-php library](http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/) for all push notification needs:

Comment: Hey : Will you please explain format of Push in Php.

Comment: @Asim I don't have much info on format, but you can use this library i mentioned, for PHP. You can reverse engineer to see the format.

Answer (score -1):

We can add more than one custom data,but, if i use `sub_action` as the name, my iPhone can't receive push msg

Java:

```
PayLoad payLoad = new PayLoad();
payLoad.addCustomDictionary("action", action_type);
payLoad.addCustomDictionary("subaction", sub_action_type);
```