# Get JSON payload data into a string from push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, push-notification

Im trying to get my JSON payload data from a push notification into a string.

```
{
 aps = {
 alert = "BG push";

 sound = ,
 };
}
```

I researched on SO and on Parse and tried various ways including this [Apple Push Notification with Sending Custom Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134155/apple-push-notification-with-sending-custom-data) however my string reruns (null) or as in this example in the JSON format

I want the `alert` data `"BG Push"` in a string so I can put this in an alert view

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ){

        // app was already in the foreground
        [PFPush handlePush:userInfo]; //<-----userInfo returns payload data in JSON format

    }

        else {                
            // app was just brought from background to foreground
            NSLog(@"App was in background and opened from Push message");

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Megger"
                                        message: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userInfo]
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles: nil];

            [alert show];

        }
  }
```

Comment: NSString* message = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *alert = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Megger"
                              message: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", alert]
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alertView show];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. (Ignoring the name collision of `string` and `alerView`), That Returns `(null)` value for `string

Comment: Try this `NSString *alert = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];`

Comment: Actually notification's data is wrapped with additional NSDictionary with `@"aps"` key. That's why direct access with `@"alert"` key doesn't work and `alert[@"aps"][@"alert"]` does.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
NSDictionary *temp = userInfo[@"aps"];
NSString *message = temp[@"alert"];
```

If it doesn't work, add this line and let me know what you get

```
NSLog( @"%@\r%@\r%@", userInfo, temp, message );
```