# send data with push notification - not returning whole push either

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have been trying for around 2 days now to get this chat app to work (really basic) that when the one user sends a message, it pops up as a remote notification on the other users screen and when they open it, it must take the second user to the specific chat (with the user that sent the message, not another chat from someone else).

I am trying to do this by unwrapping the notification, checking who the notification is from, and then taking them to the respective chat. But I cannot get the `aps` or the sent data to have the data from who it was.

I have done some research and other peoples notifications look like this:

```
{
"aps": {
     "badge": 10,
     "alert": "Test",
     "sound": "cat.caf"
},
"url": "http://www.google.com"
}
```

While mine looks like this:

```
{
alert = asd;
}
```

1) is there a way to add more info such as `sender id`, `sender name`, etc.

2) how can I make this stop popping up as an alert, and rather just always have it as a banner?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134155/apple-push-notification-with-sending-custom-data

Comment: @Sreejith THat does not explain `HOW` to add the custom data, which was the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to do it through the `.setData()` method. So here is the code:

```
var data: AnyObject = ["from" : "1", "message" : textView.text, "aps" : ["alert" : textView.text, "badge" : "1"]] as NSDictionary
push.setData(data as NSDictionary)
```

The reason it was not working earlier was because I was trying to use the `.setMessage()` as well, which overwrites the `.setData()` if it comes after, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
// Set your alert message
$message = 'How are you???!';

// Set your custom data
$customData = '{"url":"www.google.com"}';


// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'customData' => $customData
);
```

And finally push the payload.

Attaching the `php` file if you want : [Push Custom Data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=50690371018243351395)

Comment: Trying to do this in `Swift`, not `PHP`

Answer (score 0):

Parse appears to have documentation on this ... https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS

Also pretty sure that the user has control over how the notifications should appear, you as a developer can't control it