# Access userInfo dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, parse-platform, notifications

I'm trying to access the `userInfo` dictionary in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification()` so that I can choose a segue based on what kind of push was received/if any push was received. I've tried these two ways (some others too, I'm sure, I just can't remember at this point).

```
if let info = userInfo as? Dictionary<String,String> {
        var notificationType = info["notificationType"]
}


if let info: String = userInfo["notificationType"] as? String {
        //do stuff
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, I'm just not getting anything at all. If I print the userInfo dictionary, it only has one member, ["aps"], which contains the push message that gets displayed to the user, so even if I could just access this I could make a conditional using it.

I attempt to write to userData as per the Parse API:

```
let data = ["notificationType" : "coffee"]
push.setData(data)
```

So the one issue is that this doesn't seem to be setting anything, but the greater issue is that I can't get to any userInfo data.

How do you access this dictionary?

**EDIT**

some print statement results:

```
println(userInfo["aps"]) => {alert = "You've Been Invited To A Coffee Order";}

println(userInfo) => [aps: {alert = "You've Been Invited To A Coffee Order";}, type: coffee]

println(userInfo[0]) => nil

let info = userInfo as? Dictionary<String,String>
println(info) => nil
```

So it seems just the alert key is getting stuck in this `'aps'` array? dictionary? I didn't create it, it's just automatically part of `userInfo`

**Edit 2**

Here's the code where I set the data and send the push. I send the data that appears in `userInfo` from here:

```
func notifyUserOfCoffeeOrder(){
    var uQuery:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    uQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameLabel.text)

    var pushQuery:PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()
    pushQuery.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: uQuery)

    var push:PFPush = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(pushQuery)
    let data = ["type" : "coffee",
                "alert" : "You've Been Invited To A Coffee Order"]
    push.setData(data)
    push.sendPush(nil)
    println("push sent")

}
```

and here's the whole function from AppDelegate.swift, where I pull the received data out:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("getMessage", object: nil)

    if  let info = userInfo["type"] as? String {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("coffeeVC") as UIViewController

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please add the method signature where the first code part is fetched from? I'm kind of confused as to what you want to achieve, and which data you want to de-reference. Is the main goal of your example to get that the `notificationType == "coffee"`

Comment: I posted as soon as I printed those, so I realized immediately I can access the type using `userInfo["notificationType"]`, although I still would like to know why the `userInfo` data structure is built this way.

Comment: Could you copy more of the code, especially the declaration and the part with "You've been invited...", and give the print output after changing the data assignment into something like 'let data = [ "notificationType" : "coffee", "something" : "else"]'

Comment: i added the two relevant functions, is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 12):

> **EDIT:** I've know rebuilt this answer to conform with the comments given. Do note that I do not have access to Apples Push Notification services currently, and as such can't test this in the same environment as OP

It seems like the APN (or parse.com) adds a little bit here and there to the `userInfo` as you build it. Therefore my best suggestion is to use code like the following to print everything from the double dictionary which you receive. I've also provided code here to unwrap the optionals which occur as you look up something in the dictionaries.

So here is my modified example code:

```
func myApplicationFunc(didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    // NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("getMessage", object: nil)

    // Default printout of userInfo
    println("All of userInfo:\n\( userInfo)\n")

    // Print all of userInfo
    for (key, value) in userInfo {
        println("userInfo: \(key) —> value = \(value)")
    }

    if let info = userInfo["aps"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        // Default printout of info = userInfo["aps"]
        println("All of info: \n\(info)\n")

        for (key, value) in info {
            println("APS: \(key) —> \(value)")
        }


        if  let myType = info["type"] as? String {
            // Printout of (userInfo["aps"])["type"]
            println("\nFrom APS-dictionary with key \"type\":  \( myType)")

            // Do your stuff?
        }
    }
}

var userInfo : [ NSObject: AnyObject] =
[
    "aps" : [
        "alert" : "Coffee is not the answer",
        "type" : "coffee"
    ],
    "anotherType" : 123
]

myApplicationFunc(didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo)
```

This code produced the following output:

```
All of userInfo:
[anotherType: 123, aps: {
    alert = "Coffee is not the answer";
    type = coffee;
}]

userInfo: anotherType —> value = 123
userInfo: aps —> value = {
    alert = "Coffee is not the answer";
    type = coffee;
}

All of info: 
[alert: Coffee is not the answer, type: coffee]

APS: alert —> Coffee is not the answer
APS: type —> coffee

From APS-dictionary with key "type":  coffee
```

You should be able to add my code within your `application(...)` method, and hopefully you'll see the light on both how to unwrap the double dictionary, and which information is actually transferred to you.

PS! In this [answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26681346/1548472) talks about how his `setMessage` disturbed his `setData`, this might also be interesting, if there are is some code affecting your result. Still my example code, should list everything received in `userInfo`

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer. Your assumptions were correct. And I think it's the last thing you said that I'm having trouble with, userInfo holding a dictionary. I'll update my answer with some print statement results to show you.

Comment: Thanks for unpacking! Literally :)
Typo: it's `APS` not `ASP`

Comment: Thanks. You saved a night!