# how to extract parameter from Branch.io deep link url getting via push notification from Locality's. in React native

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I am using Branch.IO to generate deep links. Now the normal flow works perfectly. Opens the application on tapping the link from the mobile browser.

The problem is when I put the deep link URL in the payload of notification and tap on the notification. I will get deep link Url but what is the best way to redirect on particular screen based on url parameter in react native?.  i am not getting parameter
i am sending notification via locality's

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can send **custom data** in the payload of the notification, may be a notification type and use that type to show the desired screen on notification tap.

For how to send Custom data in payload please check:

[Apple Push Notification with Sending Custom Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134155/apple-push-notification-with-sending-custom-data/8134196)

Comment: parameter is already in Deep link url, i need solution for extracting parameter from Deep link Url.

Comment: then use regex to extract parameter from URL or javascript's split function to extract parameters (it depends on your URL)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, but i have created deep link short link from branch.io console and i have aded multiple parameter not only id. so i think its not directly return parameter with regex. so how can i redirect User to particular screen based on url parameter ?